# Play Framework code coverage in Intellij IDEA 14

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, specs2

I've created a simple Play 2.x application in Intellij IDEA 14.1.4 and decided to run tests with code coverage. Here's what I get to choose:

[image: options]

I've tried both options and when I actually run tests with code coverage, I get the following error:

With the first option:

[image: first option]

With the second one:

[image: second option]

The code of the test was generated by IDEA and I don't think it matters.

As I've found out, the problem might be with my user name, since it contains Russian symbols. The usual test run works perfectly and it only fails when I try to run with code coverage, which proves the username theory.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -ea "-javaagent:C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\coverage\lib\coverage-agent.jar=C:\Users\пс\AppData\Local\Temp\coverage0args"
>
> C:\Users\пс\

However, I was unable to find the solution since I simply don't know what to look for.

Comment: For scala projects I would recommend using [scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage). This can be integrated into your build.sbt and also integrated with github and travis. Coverage tools for java often have problems with scala code such as case classes.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look at it, but I'm working with other people and we're already using IDEA coverage. It works fine for everyone but me so I guess we won't change it just because of my problem.

Comment: I thought so. That is why I did not post it as an answer :-) But generally I think things should be integrated into the automated build instead of run manually from the IDE.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I tried to install scoverage but unfortunately it failed on the 'Add the plugin to your build with the following in project/plugins.sbt:' For some reason, it failed to resolve the dependency.